# Bash - how to make arithmetic expansion in range braces?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to do this:
`for i in {1.."$((2**3))"}; do echo "$i"; done`

But that would output `{1..8}`, which I want to execute, not output.
How to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do in like that in bash, brace expansion happens before variable does.
A c-style for loop can be an alternative.

```
for ((i = 1; i <= 2**3; i++)); do printf '%d ' "$i"; done
```

... Or if you really want to do the brace expansion use `eval` which is not advised to use but it is the only way...

```
eval echo {1..$((2**3))}
```

- See the local bash manual  for the order of expansion `PAGER='less +/^EXPANSION' man bash` and the online manual (thanks to `@Freddy`) https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html
- See `eval` in the local bash manual `PAGER='less +/^[[:blank:]]*eval\ ' man bash`

Comment: 1) Where can I find out, what operation does happen before others (that is, which expansion of whatever happens first) - the flow of execution. 2) Why it works with eval? Could it be done with subshell `$()`? It works because of the flow? Does `eval` has precedence of braces? Can you please more elaborate your answer?

Comment: No subshell can fix that, the order of expansion matters, braces first before variables, that's why `for i in {$var1.. $var2}` does not give the expected output. well eval can do many things. One of them deleting everything in your / without knowing it...

Comment: "The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and filename expansion." ([Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html))

Comment: @Herdsman What `eval` does is after the usual expansion sequence, it takes the result and does *the whole sequence again*. So in this case, `{1..$((2**3))}` becomes `{1..8}` during the arithmetic expansion step of the first sequence, then that expands to `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8` in the brace expansion step of the second sequence. The basic problem with `eval` is that shell parsing & expansion is (as you've discovered) somewhat confusing, and doing it twice is *more confusing*. You need extra levels of quotes and/or escapes, data can get treated as syntax, etc etc.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, 1) Why does `eval` expands the WHOLE command/line, and not only what is after it (that is - its argument). 2) If the usage of `eval` is more confusing, what is its purpose, or when does using `eval` is advantageous and makes sense?

Comment: @Herdsman I don't know the exact thought process that went into creating `eval`, but in general the original shell (and unix) philosophy tended to emphasize making it easy to do things, as opposed to making it easy to control exactly *which* things were done. In retrospect, this turns out to be unsafe, and if you want your script/code/whatever to do *exactly* what you want (rather than just something similar to what you want), you sometimes have to avoid doing things in the obvious way, and instead use a more complex and non-obvious way that (again, in retrospect) actually works better.

Comment: Variable expansion is a good example of this. If you just use `$varname`, the shell will try to split it into multiple words (on whitespace), and expand anything that looks like a wildcard into a list of matching filenames. You usually don't want either of these things to happen, and when you do you probably only want one or the other, and may want control over *which* whitespaces and wildcards are parsed and which are left alone. So, the right answer is almost always to double-quote variable references to keep this from happening, and use something like arrays if you want multiple words.

Answer (score 2):

You could to use `seq` instead of range braces:

```
for i in $(seq 1 $((2**3))); do echo "$i"; done
```