# How do i place the input arguments on a bash script cell?

Tags: bash

I have

```
numdays=$1
startday=$2

# This calculates the dates to retrieve queries
for i in {1..$numdays}; do
  StringArray+=($(date -I -d '${startday} + $i days'))
done
```

But it's returning `date: invalid date ‘${startday} + $i days’`, but I'm not sure how to build the strings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61398661/bash-how-to-make-arithmetic-expansion-in-range-braces/61398716#61398716 does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Braces expansion `{x..y}` happens *before* variable substitution `$x`. So `{0..$x}` will not work - braces expansion will do nothing and just expand `x`.

Variable expansion does not happen in single qoutes. So `'${startday}'` is just equal to literally the string, and the expansion of `${...}` will *not* happen. Remember to put expansions inside *double* quotes.

In your case, you could use `seq`:

```
for i in $(seq $numdays); do
    ... "${startday} + $i days"
```

I would:

```
readarray -t StringArray < <(seq $numdays | xargs -I{} date -I -d "$startday + {} days")
```